# Travelling wave ansatz

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)-w,~~w_t=\varepsilon (u-\gamma w).~~(*)
$$

Consider the ansatz
$$
(u(x,t),w(x,t))=(u(\xi),w(\xi)),~~\xi=x+ct, c\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Putting this ansatz into $(*)$, it is said that we get
$$
u'=v\\
v'=cv-f(u)+w\\
w'=\frac{\varepsilon}{c}(u-\gamma w),
$$
where $'=d/d\xi$.

I do not see that.

Consider $\frac{d}{dt}u(\xi)$, then the inner derivative is $c$, but what is the outer derivative?

Answer (score 1):

The point of this is to convert the partial differential equations with functions of two variables into a system of ordinary differential equations with functions of one variable. It's a bit misleading to use $u(x, t) = u(\xi)$ because the $u$'s are actually different functions.

Suppose we define $u(x,t) = U(x + c t)$ and $w(x, y) = W(x + c t)$. Now the capital letters are functions of a single variable being applied to $\xi = x + c t$.

Looking at the first two equations, we have 
$u_{xx} = U''(x + c t)$, $u_t = c U'(x + c t)$, and $w_t = c W'(x + c t)$. Now you can rearrange the equations into:

\begin{align*}
U'(\xi) &= U''(\xi) + f(U(\xi)) - W(\xi)\\
c W'(\xi) &= \varepsilon(U(\xi) - \gamma W(\xi))
\end{align*}

Using the substitution $V(\xi) = U'(\xi)$ you can get the system you stated. This is a first order nonlinear system or ODEs. Whether or not you can get a closed form solution will depend on the nature of $f$.

Comment: My problem is to see that $u_{xx}=U''(x+ct), u_t=cU'(x+ct)$, where $'=d/d\xi$.

Comment: Using the chain rule, you have $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(x, t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} U(\xi(x, t)) = \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t} = U'(\xi) c$.

Comment: What I do not understand is: We want to have the derivative with respect to $t$. So the inner function surely is given by $x+ct$ and if we take the derivative w.r.t. to t, we surely have $c$. But I do not understand why for the outer function, we take the derivative with respect to $\xi$.

Comment: @mathfemi Because this is how chain rule applies in this case, because you have series of mappings $(x, t) \mapsto \xi \mapsto U$.